# Create a unique id for a whole SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, rdf, option-type, uuid, fuseki

I need a unique id (uuid) for a whole query independent of the number of matches.

Consider the following Data

```
@prefix ex:<http://www.example.org/>
ex:John ex:knows ex:Kathrin.
ex:John ex:knows ex:Peter.
ex:John ex:worksAt ex:coolShop.
```

The data tells us that John knows some people and works at coolShop.

Now we have an INSERT query:

```
1   PREFIX ex:<http://www.example.org/>
2   INSERT{
3     ?john ex:knows         ex:Alan.
4     ?john ex:hasRandomUUID ?uuid.
5   }
6   WHERE{
7     ?john ex:knows ?friend.
8     OPTIONAL{
9       ?john ex:worksAt ?shop
10      BIND(STRUUID() AS ?uuid)
11     }
12   }
```

This query inserts that john knows Alan.
Furthermore, I want to insert a unique id for John denoted by `?john ex:hasRandomUUID ?uuid`. But I want to add this unique id only if John works somewhere. Therefore, we bind `BIND(STRUUID() AS ?uuid)` in the optional clause. So if `?john ex:worksAt ?shop` matches we bind an unique id to `?uuid`. (Assume that a person can only work at on place at once and assume that there may be more than one triple in the optional clause.)

So far so good.

My problem now is that due to the fact that `?john ex:knows ?friend` in line 7 matches twice, `BIND(STRUUID() AS ?uuid)` is evaluated twice and thus, 2 different uuids are generated. Due to the fact that 2 different uuids are generated, two triples of the form `ex:John ex:hasRandomUUID uuid` are inserted even though I only want one.
How can I make sure that only one uuid is created independently from any matches or that only one triple of the form  `ex:John ex:hasRandomUUID uuid` is inserted.

Please not that I cannot use something like `Bind(ex:John AS ?john)` instead of line 6.

I work with Apache Jena Fuseki.

Thank you very much.

EDIT:
This worked for me:

```
1   PREFIX ex:<http://www.example.org/>
2   INSERT{
3     ?john ex:knows         ex:Alan.
4     ?john ex:hasRandomUUID ?uuid.
5   }
6   WHERE{
7     ?john ex:knows ?friend.
8     {
9       OPTIONAL{
10        ?john ex:worksAt ?shop
11        BIND(STRUUID() AS ?uuid)
12      }
13    }
14  }
```

By adding line 8 and line 13 the whole `OPTIONAL` clause is put in a sub query. This leads to `STRUUID()` being evaluated only once and only on triple of the form `ex:John ex:hasRandomUUID uuid` is inserted in the dataset.

Comment: Usually, it works with putting it inside `{ }` to evaluate it just once, but not sure whether this also holds inside the `OPTIONAL`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Why not `md5(str(?john))`?

Comment: Ok. -the problem is that I don't get the real purpose of your query given the hard coded `ex:knows ex:Alan` - what happens if there is another person not working anywhere? Anyways, a workaround to the current query + sample data (and only to this): use a subquery `{select ?john {
     ?john ex:knows ?friend.
     } group by ?john}`  instead of `?john ex:knows ?friend.`  And yes, it's likely to fail if somebody works at multiple shops. But as I aid, I don't know the whole data nor the use case

Comment: Thank you very much! The example is very artificial because explaining the actual situation would take a lot of preliminaries, so I tried to reduce it. Nevertheless, your solution works but I found a solution more fitting for my needs:

If i simply put the whole `OPTIONAL` clause into a subquery `{ OPTIONAL {... }}`    `STRUUID` will generate only one unique id.

Comment: Use a subquery, and apply `SELECT DISTINCT` for the resources that should receive a UUID.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to allocation the potential ID when the query matches `?john` then assign it to the actual variable when it is needed:

```
WHERE
  {
    ?john ex:knows ?friend .
    BIND ( STRUUID() AS ?uuidX )
    {
      OPTIONAL
        {
          ?john ex:worksAt ?shop .
          BIND ( ?uuidX AS ?uuid )
        }
    }
  }
```